# C++ Visual Studios : can not open include file ... eh?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Sorry for posting such a lowly beginner's question, but I just still don't know my way around Visual Studios yet.  I'm trying to compile a code in C++ Visual Studios:

```
#include "Banana.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    fruit::Banana banana;
    banana.dance();
    return 0;
}
```

and I'm getting an error

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file: 'Banana.h': No such
>   file or directory

But in the Solution Explorer under the project that I'm working with there is a source folder labeled "fruit/Header Files" and within that folder is "Banana.h".  I thought that everything in the source folders within the same project were automatically on the source path.  What gives?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will need to configure additional include paths. If you go to the Project Properties, you'll find it under `Configuration Properties`, `C/C++` at the top.

Answer (score 4):

The Solution Explorer doesn't show if the .h files are actually usable.  Whether a header file is usable depends on whether it's reachable, which is determined by the list of directories to include from.  I think the solution includes header files so it knows to recompile if they change.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the tab header of the source code file and choose `open file location`. Then, start there and try to locate the `Banana.h` file and move it either to the same directory (and re-add it to the solution), or change the `#include` line accordingly. You could also add the directory where `Banana.h` is located to the list of include paths (`project settings -> c++ -> include directories`).

Answer (score 0):

It's very confusing, because the Solution Manager uses virtual filepaths, whereas #include uses real filepaths. This way, you can make filters in SM and have no disk change, and add files that you can't include, etc.